# Implement HTML template in Typo3, content don't work or my mistake

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I try that implement html template in typo3.
With this tutorial: http://wiki.typo3.org/Templating_Tutorial_-_Basics

All subparts and makers perfectly work, but content subparts CONTENTMIDDLE and CONTENTRIGHT don't work.

I did all the same from tutorial, but don't work, nothing are showing.

subpart

In this area, should be changed content which input from backend.

I tried with this, but nothing happens:

```
CONTENTRIGHT = CONTENT
CONTENTRIGHT < styles.content.getRight
```

---

```
# get content, right
CONTENTRIGHT = CONTENT
CONTENTRIGHT {
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.where = colPos=2
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
}
```

**EDIT**>>>

I solved.

Problem is what I not included css_styled_content, ie. I have changed root page, and forget thet change this in template->Includes.

Screenshot> http://www.dodaj.rs/f/15/Za/PWfwzG3/forgetinclude.jpg

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way it gets out of the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Template->Includes and include **css_styled_content**