# typo3 - Adding content to the footer

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, footer

I am editing a template in typo3. I have problem with adding content into footer. In my index.html my footer looks like this:

```
 <div id="footer">
   <div id="footerLeft"></div>
   <ul id="footerCenter"> </ul>
   <div id="footerRight"> </div>
 </div>
```

I have managed to put background image to my footer, and stick it at the bottom of my page in css:

```
 #footer{
 width:100%;
 height:292px;
 background:url(../img/prechod_stranka-paticka1920x145.png) no-repeat top center;
 background-color:#4e4b47;
 position:static;
 bottom:0px;
 }
```

Now, I want to put some content in divs(footerLeft, footerCenter, footerRight). These divs were part of the template from the beginning of my work on this website. I am having very hard time to find a place where to put that content. In "footerCenter", there is already Menu of my page. However, in typo3 backend I cannot see where it is.

Can anyone help me please?Thx

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TYPO3! You will have to read up on how it works / is configured, else you'll run into the next issue very soon.

- Start here: http://wiki.typo3.org/Templating_Tutorial_-_Basics
- On Typoscript in general: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/.
- Or you can install the [Introduction package](http://typo3.org/download/) and study how it is set up.

To partially answer your question: use Typoscript / css_styled_content to rout the content you edit in the backend to the template. There are several ways to do that, here's an example for the simplest but also most old-school way ("markers"): [Implement HTML template in Typo3, content don't work or my mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732387/implement-html-template-in-typo3-content-dont-work-or-my-mistake)